# How can l add cells to UICollectionView with SwiftRx?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

My task is to add UICollectionView with several cells to the cell of UITableView using SwiftRx and MVVM pattern.

I add empty collectionView to tableView, but I can't figure out how to add some cells to it using SwiftRx.

Here is my CollectionCellView (also I have a method for layout):

```
private(set) var bag = DisposeBag()
private let viewModel: SocialMediaCellViewModel

private let image: UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.image = UIImage(named: "plusSocialMedia")
    return img
}()

private let telegramButton: SocialMediaButton = {
    let bt = SocialMediaButton()
    bt.setImage(SocialMedia.telegram.icon, for: .normal)
    return bt
}()
```

If you can help me to figure out what I have to write in my ViewModel and how to correctly write bindViewModel() method in CollectionCellView, it will be so amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The library has an example of how to do it here RxCocoa/iOS/UICollectionView+Rx.swift

```
/**
Binds sequences of elements to collection view items.

- parameter source: Observable sequence of items.
- parameter cellFactory: Transform between sequence elements and view cells.
- returns: Disposable object that can be used to unbind.
 
 Example

     let items = Observable.just([
         1,
         2,
         3
     ])

     items
     .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { (collectionView, row, element) in
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NumberCell
         cell.value?.text = "\(element) @ \(row)"
         return cell
     }
     .disposed(by: disposeBag)
*/
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This example l have to re-write in my Cell? But l still don't understand what to put in my viewmodel

Comment: Yes, put `items` in your view model.